# Java RegExpr with Pattern class multigroup

Tags: java, regex

I've this situation:

My string:

```
Try a lot of match groups

[COD_BODY="AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL="Apri link1"] come on Taranto

[ COD_BODY="AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL="Apri link2"]

[ COD_BODY ="AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL="Apri link3"]

[ COD_BODY = "AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL="Apri link4"]

[ COD_BODY = "AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL ="Apri link5"]

[ COD_BODY = "AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL = "Apri link6"]

[ COD_BODY = "AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI" , LABEL = "Apri link5" ]
```

I've written this mask (in Java):

```
"(\\[(\\s*)\\bCOD_BODY(\\s*)=(\\s*)\"(.*)?\"(\\s*),(\\s*)LABEL(\\s*)=(\\s*)\"(.*)?\"(\\s*)\\]*)"
```

I've used this pattern in Pattern.compile

Now... if I try on these sites:

http://www.regexr.com/

and http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester

with this pattern:

```
(\[(\s*)\bCOD_BODY(\s*)=(\s*)"(.*)?"(\s*),(\s*)LABEL(\s*)=(\s*)"(.*)?"(\s*)\]*)
```

I've removed double \ used in Java to escape special chars

The result is: 7 matches found!

But in Java `while(matcher.find())` loop one time only instead seven!

Please, where's my fault?

If you have further informations, please comment this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Regex {

    public Regex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Try a lot of match groups\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "[COD_BODY=\"AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI\", LABEL=\"Apri link1\"] come on Taranto\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "[ COD_BODY=\"AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI\", LABEL=\"Apri link2\"]\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "[ COD_BODY =\"AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI\", LABEL=\"Apri link3\"]\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "[ COD_BODY = \"AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI\", LABEL=\"Apri link4\"]\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "[ COD_BODY = \"AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI\", LABEL =\"Apri link5\"]\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "[ COD_BODY = \"AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI\", LABEL = \"Apri link6\"]\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "[ COD_BODY = \"AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI\" , LABEL = \"Apri link5\" ]";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\[(\\s*)\\bCOD_BODY(\\s*)=(\\s*)\"(.*)?\"(\\s*),(\\s*)LABEL(\\s*)=(\\s*)\"(.*)?\"(\\s*)\\]*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }

}
```

Results:

```
[COD_BODY="AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL="Apri link1"]
[ COD_BODY="AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL="Apri link2"]
[ COD_BODY ="AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL="Apri link3"]
[ COD_BODY = "AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL="Apri link4"]
[ COD_BODY = "AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL ="Apri link5"]
[ COD_BODY = "AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI", LABEL = "Apri link6"]
[ COD_BODY = "AZI_DIP-ANAG_AZI" , LABEL = "Apri link5" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your illumination. The error was my pre convert \n\r in <br /> HTML tag. So I swapped two operations, so Java recognize 7 groups!

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern matches whole string you should not call `find()` in loop. Instead you have to extract groups from matcher:

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);}
if (!m.find()) { // call find only once!
   return;
}
int n = m.groupCount();
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // starting from 1
    String capture = m.group(i); // this is the captured group.
    // deal with capture
}
```

Comment: I think the pattern do not try to match the whole string. (No `$` or `^`.)

Comment: @GáborBakos, I mean that it fully matches fragment that contains all needed captured groups.

Comment: It is very interesting to know the reasons of downvoter that down votes completely correct answer.

Comment: I think you are trying to answer something else. (Though I can be wrong.) This question seems to be about the `find()` method, not the groups. The `find()` method certainly can be called more than once, it will advance after each call to the next occurrence. The OP stated that with other tools he or she was able to find 7 occurrences with similar pattern, while with Java only 1.

Comment: This question is about wrong usage of pattern API. OP should not call find() in loop to get all his captured groups. This is what I recommended.

Comment: Your answer it's ok too.